# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED .dev redirecting to https

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari

Today I went to bring up our `.dev` localhost environment to do some work and noticed that the site was redirecting to https.  I thought this was strange and assumed it was searching for the server after being unable to location it on port 80.

This was resulting in an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.  This was perplexing as it was loading fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

The solution here is that Google purchase the `.dev` TLD a year or two ago and made announcements that these would stop working at some point.  I knew this, but it escaped me that this was what was causing this issue.

As it turns out, the most recent versions of Chrome and Safari both add the `.dev` TLD to the `HSTS` list, forcing HTTPS compliance.  This is likely an authenticity move by Google and Apple for the `.dev` TLD, in order to prevent domain spoofing.

Regardless, if you rely on HTTP support for your `.dev` TLD, it's not going to work anymore.  Save yourself the time and headache, change the TLD to something like `.test` and wait until the proposal for implementation of the `.localhost` TLD has been implemented.

Note: `.local` while it sounds nice is used by Apple's Bonjour service for discovery.  This is not advised.

Update:  Google has now gone and starting selling domain registrations on the .dev TLD.  Thanks Google!